# Start Django 'manage.py runserver' within jupyter notebook

Tags: python, django, jupyter-notebook

I would like to create small application in Django.

However, main requirement for this application is to be started within jupyter notebook, as every user will have such application locally.

Plotly dash (from which I would like to rewrite this app) allows

```
app.runserver()
```

inside jupyter cell, which afterwards starts the app.
However this is not available for django in the jupyter notebook.

I could do

```
!python manage.py runserver
```

This spawns server correctly.
But this server is not 'killable' using the interrupt button inside jupyter notebook - which is important feature of this approach.
Same applies for `os.system` or `subprocess.Popen`.

I tried also approach from this question: [Django runserver from Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30893418/django-runserver-from-python-script)
Which does not work in the jupyter notebook unfortunately. This raises `zmq.error.ZMQError: Address in use`

Is there any other approach which I could try?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you would like the Notebook to send some commands to the Django app running on the same machine, right? In that case, could you not package the two together and have them start using a single script. Then you could direct requests to something like "localhost:8000" from whatever HTTP messaging library you'd like.

Comment: how could I direct requests to localhost? this could be possible, however the start from jupyter notebook is preferable

Comment: Sorry. I completely missed following up on this. Not sure if this helps now. But I was thinking of a library like 'requests' where you could actually do something like `requests.get('http://localhost:8000')` and then from the output of this function call, get the data as a JSON. You could then do whatever is needed with it.